# Source for Rav Shach story (bentsching from a book from age 100)

Tags: bentching, story-identification, rav-shach

[In  *Torah Tidbits*, issue 1372, Rabbi Shalom Rosner wrote, in part:](https://download.torahtidbits.com/1372%20Naso/Torah---Tibits%20Naso%20Shavuos%201372%20Rabbi%20Rosner.pdf)

> When Rav Shach turned 100, he told his students that he was going to accept upon himself a new resolution. The students were curious: What new practice is Rav Shach going to adopt at age 100? He told them: “I am going to be careful to always bentch (recite the blessing after meals) from a bentcher [=book].

I find this a little hard to believe. (No litotes intended. I'm not saying it's impossible — just that it's somewhat hard to believe.) After all, *Mishna B'rura* (185:1) says "one who is particular will take care to bless, [*l'chat'chila*](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/702/170), from a book and not by heart", so I'd imagine this is something [Rabbi Shach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elazar_Shach) may well have been careful about already by the time he hit age one hundred. So I'm seeking a better source than Rabbi Rosner's say-so. Anyone have one?

Comment: http://www.hidush.co.il/hidush.asp?id=6908 Says here this was a general piece of advice he would give. Further googling shows that this was something he meticulously followed all his life and when he was very old and a tube for eating was inserted in his body, he was very upset because he could no longer bentch. While I couldn't find a source for this particular story, considering Rav Shach's attitude towards bentching, I assume that the idea conveyed is that he was always looking to improve his bentching.

Comment: I certainly remember Rav Shach having made comments about the importance of bentching from a bencher before he was 100 yet

Comment: You could ask Rav Rosner https://www.facebook.com/Rabbi-Shalom-Rosner-158564311186014/ !

Comment: @Avrohom I e-mailed him as soon as I had posted this question, inviting him to reply here.